# ASP.NET Core Web API with OData controller needs to use fluent API for composite key

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I have an existing API that now has tables in the database it uses which have to have a composite key.
I used fluent API to define the keys in the dbcontext.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
     {
        //relationship modeling
        modelBuilder.Entity<Reports>().HasMany(r => r.Screenshots).WithOne().HasForeignKey(r => new { r.ReportId, r.itemTypeId });
        modelBuilder.Entity<Images>().HasOne(s => s.Reports).WithMany(s => s.Screenshots).HasForeignKey(s => new { s.ReportId, s.itemTypeId });
        modelBuilder.Entity<EpicReportsChildList>().HasOne(e => e.Reports).WithMany(e => e.EpicReports).HasForeignKey(e => new { e.TemplateId, e.parentTypeId });
        modelBuilder.Entity<Images>().HasOne(s => s.EpicReports).WithMany(s => s.Screenshots).HasForeignKey(s => new { s.ReportId, s.itemTypeId });

        
    }
```

I have the startup file with the following:

```
private IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
    {
        var oDatabuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        oDatabuilder.EntitySet<Reports>("reports");

        return oDatabuilder.GetEdmModel();
    }
```

The API is returning the following error:

Entity type `EpicReportsChildList` has composite primary key defined with data annotations. To set composite primary key, use fluent API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Entity type EpicReportsChildList has composite primary key defined
> with data annotations. To set composite primary key, use fluent API.

As the error message said, perhaps you are configuring the composite primary key both using the data annotations or the fluent API method.

From the [EF Core Keys document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=fluent-api), we can find that: **Composite keys can only be configured using the Fluent API; conventions will never setup a composite key, and you can not use Data Annotations to configure one.**

So, please check the related model and try to remove the data annotations: `[Key]` attribute or `[ForeignKey]` attibute.

More detail information about configure relationship with composite key, you could check the following articles (The many to many relationship joining table was configured to use  the composite primary key, you could refer to them):

[EF one to many on part of composite primary key](https://entityframeworkcore.com/knowledge-base/53491217/ef-one-to-many-on-part-of-composite-primary-key)

[Configure Many-to-Many Relationships in Entity Framework Core](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-ef-core.aspx)

[Configuring Many To Many Relationships in Entity Framework Core](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/many-to-many-relationship-configuration)